# setting time to delete booking php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set time limit in reservation system. Such that Users must
have the ability to remove their bookings, but not before the lapse of 1 minute away from the time when the booking has been entered

```
 <?php 
 require_once 'connection.php';


if(isset($_SESSION['book'])){

if (isset($_SESSION['book_time'])){
    if (time()-$_SESSION['book_time']>= 60){

        if (isset($_POST['delete'])){       

$machineID = $_POST['machine_id'];
$starttime = $_POST['start_time'];

$qry = "DELETE FROM bookings where machine_id = '$machineID' AND 
 start_time = '$starttime'";

$result =  mysql_query($qry,$conn);
if ($result){

    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
        $message[] = 'Booking Deleted form DB';
    }
  }

    }
}
 }
  }
?>
```

but it couldn't remove even after 1 min with this script....what could be possible problem

Comment: just before you asked same question ...

Comment: Ok, what is $starttime  ?

Comment: what are you getting in $_session['book_time'] ?

Comment: yea, i forgot to include what the problem was  and no one answered. thats the reason why i posted it again

Comment: You are using deprecated code (mysql_* functions) consider switching to mysqli or pdo. On top of that you have not cleaned your input, the code is vulnerable to injects.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])){       

$machineID = $_POST['machine_id'];
$starttime = $_POST['start_time'];
```

To

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && (time()-$_SESSION['book_time']>= 60)){       

$machineID = $_POST['machine_id'];
$starttime = $_POST['start_time'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
iF ((int)$starttime+60 > time()) {
$qry = "DELETE FROM bookings where machine_id = '$machineID' AND start_time = '$starttime'";
}
```